# chrome.usb.openDevice null handle returned

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome

I am using cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-usb to access a USB device (finger printer reader).

***chrome.usb.getDevices()*** returns correctly the USB device connected to the Andriod host machine (I get the correct VendorId and ProductId).

***chrome.usb.openDevice()*** returns a null device handle for the USB device.

I traced into the openDevice() code, and found this step which returns msgs = "***62 F09 ChromeUsb595160930 sPermission request not yet implemented***". This indicates to me a permission issue?

```
function androidExec(success, fail, service, action, args) {
if (bridgeSecret < 0) {
    // If we ever catch this firing, we'll need to queue up exec()s
    // and fire them once we get a secret. For now, I don't think
    // it's possible for exec() to be called since plugins are parsed but
    // not run until until after onNativeReady.
    throw new Error('exec() called without bridgeSecret');
}
// Set default bridge modes if they have not already been set.
// By default, we use the failsafe, since addJavascriptInterface breaks too often
if (jsToNativeBridgeMode === undefined) {
    androidExec.setJsToNativeBridgeMode(jsToNativeModes.JS_OBJECT);
}

// Process any ArrayBuffers in the args into a string.
for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (utils.typeName(args[i]) == 'ArrayBuffer') {
        args[i] = base64.fromArrayBuffer(args[i]);
    }
}

var callbackId = service + cordova.callbackId++,
    argsJson = JSON.stringify(args);

if (success || fail) {
    cordova.callbacks[callbackId] = {success:success, fail:fail};
}

var msgs = nativeApiProvider.get().exec(bridgeSecret, service, action, callbackId, argsJson);
// If argsJson was received by Java as null, try again with the PROMPT bridge mode.
// This happens in rare circumstances, such as when certain Unicode characters are passed over the bridge on a Galaxy S2.  See CB-2666.
if (jsToNativeBridgeMode == jsToNativeModes.JS_OBJECT && msgs === "@Null arguments.") {
    androidExec.setJsToNativeBridgeMode(jsToNativeModes.PROMPT);
    androidExec(success, fail, service, action, args);
    androidExec.setJsToNativeBridgeMode(jsToNativeModes.JS_OBJECT);
} else if (msgs) {
    messagesFromNative.push(msgs);
    // Always process async to avoid exceptions messing up stack.
    nextTick(processMessages);
}
```

The ***AndroidManifest.xml*** contains the following permissions:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USB"/>
```

Have I missed a relevant one?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Android are you using? Cordova does not yet support the new permission model of Android M, so that's a possible issue.

Comment: I am using 4.4 KitKat. I tried to use permissions USE_FINGERPRINT and MANAGE_USB (as seen in my example) - but that is just a guess as there didn't seem be anything else appropriate. What should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting this TODO:

```
if (!mUsbManager.hasPermission(usbDev)) {
  // TODO: Implement dynamic permission request.
  throw new UsbError("Permission request not yet implemented");
}
```

until that is implemented you need to statically assign permission in the APK's manifest for the specific VID/PID of the device(s) you want to open, as per [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html#example).

i.e. put something like this in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/usb_device_filter" />
```

And add the appropriate res/xml/usb_device_filter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <usb-device vendor-id="6353" product-id="1234" />
</resources>
```

Obviously replacing 6353 and 1234 with the decimal encoding of your VID & PID, same as would be used in the "usbDevices" field in manifest.json in normal chrome app.
(Ideally the manifest xml lines would be autogenerated by the CCA toolchain, based on the supplied manifest.json.)

Comment: Thanks - that did it!